# Pure Python abc/ABCMeta implementation?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, abc, pep

It would be interesting to read the original pure Python implementation of `abc` module, described in [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/).

Unfortunately, the [link to a sample implementation from original PEP](https://svn.python.org/view/sandbox/trunk/abc/xyz.py) leads to a password protected SVN repository on python.org. I don't know where exactly to get a password for it.

At the same time, the standard lib already contains only a stub-ish file with the real implementation migrated to CPython level (as I understand).

Could somebody help with the original version of `abc`?..

Answer (score 0):

Since the ABCMeta class was at some point not implemented in C, the previous implementation in Python can found in the CPython repository on Github by inspecting the [commits to Lib/abc.py file](https://github.com/python/cpython/commits/main/Lib/abc.py). Here it's visible that the re-implementation of ABCMeta in C was committed on February 18th, 2018. The commit before this contains the latest Python-only implementation, link [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ae12f5d4c98f2095c2aadd58981453e955044697/Lib/abc.py). If you're interested in the first committed implementation, you can find this in the commit history I've linked to as well.